# Handlebars compile function with options parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I want to minify my template when handlebars compiles it in a NodeJS environment.

I searched for this and discovered the `handlebars.compile(templateLoaded);` has more parameters to pass to it than just the template to compiler. I would like to know how to pass a minify option for function and others options that I can pass.

Here is a link to the handlebars code that allows this:
https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/271106d43fae96fc1287898568d000b871f19084/lib/handlebars/compiler/javascript-compiler.js

Pay attention to line 46 and 48.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following resource: http://www.adamwadeharris.com/how-to-precompile-handlebars-templates/

You can pass it (if you have the cli tool via `npm -g install handlebars`) the -m flag to minimize, so it would be something like: `handlebars -m js/templates/ js/templates/templates.js`

and then instead of:

```
var source   = $("#handlebarsScriptId").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

you pass:
`var template = Handlebars.templates.handlebarsScriptId;`

and you'll need to include in your html:

```
<script src="js/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="js/templates/templates.js"></script>
```